# How to Re-Use Views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I create "partials" and re-use them throughout my Backbone application? For example, what Backbone convention/methodology should I follow that will allow me to create a navigation bar "view" and re-use it in all my views in my application? Essentially, I'm looking to replicate Rails' layouts and partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i've been using it at this very moment,
in your specific situation, the given navigation bar,

i don't even have an app view, i got my page, with certain default html in it.
and it holds a few placeholders for views, the main content, the search view, 
and as said, a navigation bar view. i don't have to re-use a navigation view in other views
since it is not inside my page's view. so when i change the page, the navigation stays

it listens to certain events called from the router, and it will change the state of my navigation view depending on that event's arguments.

if you however really want to work with views and re-use them
take a look into the layout manager being developed by Tim Branyen https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager, it is a backbone plugin that does many of the things you are asking.

i have not used it before, except in a small test application, but it looks promissing.

**edit**

as requested, here is some example code, as i explained how i work in this app with my navigation,
it might not be the most advanced demo, but it is just an idea how to change something in 1 view from another.

i have an event aggregator defined in my code:

```
    var eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

i have a navigation view:

```
    Navigation.Views.Nav = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            eventAggregator.bind("navigation:route", this.highlight);
        },

        highlight: function (arg) {
            $('.active', this.el).removeClass('active');
            $('li', this.el)
                .filter(function () {
                    return $(this).data('nav') == arg;
                })
                .addClass('active');
        }

    })

// for the size of the code, i removed many elements, and only left the most important parts,
// as you can see, the navigation view, binds to my event event aggregator object, to listen to any 'navigation:route' event.
```

and of course i have a Router that loads other views:

```
    Movies.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        views: {},

        initialize: function () {
            this.showView = App.showView;
            this.views.Edit = new Movies.Views.Edit({});
            this.views.List = new Movies.Views.List({ collection: Movies.List });
            this.views.Detail = new Movies.Views.Detail({});
        },

        routes: {
            "movies": "loadMovies",
            "movies/add": "addMovie",
            "movie/:slug": "loadMovie",
            "movie/:slug/edit": "editMovie"
        },

        // show the list of all movies.
        loadMovies: function () {
            this.showView(this.views.List);
            eventAggregator.trigger('navigation:route', 'movies');
        },

        // find the movie with the given slug, and render it to the screen.
        loadMovie: function (slug) {
            this.views.Detail.model = Movies.List.detect(function (movie) {
                return movie.get('Slug') === slug;
            });
            this.showView(this.views.Detail);
            eventAggregator.trigger('navigation:route', 'movies');
        },

        // find the movie with the given slug, and render it's edit template to the screen.
        editMovie: function (slug) {
            this.views.Edit = Movies.List.detect(function (movie) {
                return movie.get('Slug') === slug;
            });

            this.showView(this.views.Edit);
            eventAggregator.trigger('navigation:route', 'movies');
        }
    });

// most important part here is, you see how every routing function, has the  eventAggregator.trigger('navigation:route', 'movies'); which basically triggers the event (on the eventAggregator, the above listed view, binds to that event and when it comes in it calls a function, in my case this just sets an active class on the menu item.
```

so, while i'm not technically calling 1 view from another, it is the same principle,
you can raise events from anywhere, on an eventAggregator object, and listen to those events and act upon them.

Comment: Could you clarify how you're managing the `events` in your navigation bar? Further, how are you handling something like pagination, where depending on default HTML is not an option?